# POST Video in arvancloud

Tags: post, video, cloud

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type="file"]').change(function (e) {
            let file = e.target.files[0]
            let des = $("#text").val();
            let channelId = "9109b7bc-f362-4a15-a2f8-487ce005ebfb"
            let authorization = "Apikey bc6c276d-b748-41c3-b359-e824bb31034e";
            var settings = {
                "url": "https://napi.arvancloud.com/vod/2.0/channels/9109b7bc-f362-4a15-a2f8-487ce005ebfb/videos",
                "method": "POST",
                "timeout": 0,
                "headers": {
                    "Authorization": "Apikey bc6c276d-b748-41c3-b359-e824bb31034e",
                    "Accept-Language": "en",
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },

                "data": JSON.stringify({
                    "title": "alireza",
                    "convert_mode":"auto",
                    "file_id":"*****"
                })
            }


            $.ajax(settings, file).done(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            });

        });
    })
</script>
```

---

err in console log browser
{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"file_id":["The selected file_id is invalid."]}}

---

Everything I posted didn't work (guide, number random)

---

Problems with "file_id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>
<body>
<input type="file">
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tus-js-client@latest/dist/tus.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type="file"]').change(async function (e) {
            let file = e.target.files[0]
            let channelId = "2caf1ce7-34d5-4266-81fc-7a44f6e3dea1"
            let url=`https://napi.arvancloud.com/vod/2.0/channels/${channelId}/files`
            let authorization = "Apikey f56e3b70-720f-4118-ad89-58a5d95b7158";
            let fileId;

            let upload = new tus.Upload(file, {
                id: 'Tus',
                resume: true,
                chunkSize: 1048576, // 1MB
                endpoint: options.url,
                retryDelays: [0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500],
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": authorization,
                    "Accept-Language": "en",
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "tus-resumable": "1.0.0"
                },
                metadata: {
                    filename: file.name,
                    filetype: file.type,
                },
                onError: function (error) {
                    console.log("Failed because: " + error)
                },
                onProgress: function (bytesUploaded, bytesTotal) {
                    var percentage = (bytesUploaded / bytesTotal * 100).toFixed(2)
                    console.log(bytesUploaded, bytesTotal, percentage + "%")
                },
                 onSuccess:function () {
                    console.log("Download %s from %s", upload.file.name, upload.url)
                    fileId = String(upload.url).substr(88, 125)
                     var opti = {
                         "url": "https://napi.arvancloud.com/vod/2.0/channels/" + channelId + "/videos",
                         "method": "POST",
                         "timeout": 0,
                         "headers": {
                             "Authorization": authorization,
                             "Accept-Language": "en",
                             "Accept": "application/json",
                             "Content-Type": "application/json"
                         },
                         "data": JSON.stringify({
                             "title": file.name,
                             "file_id": fileId,
                             "convert_mode": "auto"
                         }),
                     };
                     $.ajax(opti).done(function (response) {
                         console.log(response);
                     });

                }

            })
            upload.start()
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```